# Importing an HTML table as Excel file into SAP

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, excel, sap-erp

We need to create an `.xls` file in ASP .NET which will be imported into SAP. Currently we're writing an HTML table into the response object. I'd like to know if SAP can import `.xls` files that are in fact HTML tables.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that I've answered your question.  Do you still pass .xls related data through as part of the response, or did you just want to know if SAP can accept formats other than .xls?

Are you consuming a webservice from SAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP can accept a complex array as input usting a Web service or the .NET connector. It does not have to be an .xls file, as long as the data is structured logically, and the SAP developer knows what data to expect.